# DML statistics on a table

Tags: database, postgresql, temp-tables

We're using **PostgreSQL 8.2**.

In our application, we heavily use a temporary table (REPORTTEMP) for report 
generation purpose. All type of DML statements are performed in this table, but UPDATE
statement is comparatively very low with INSERTs and DELETEs.  So, at any point 
of time, after completion of the transaction, record count in this table will 
always be zero.

My question is, how do I find out how many INSERTs, UPDATEs and DELETEs are
happening in this table, that is hit count of a table.  I require this statistics for further tuning from the 
performance aspect.

I also read about **PostgreSQL's Statistics Collector** here
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/interactive/monitoring-stats.html
but this comes at the expense of additional run-time overhead.

Before enabling this statistcs collector, is there any different/better way in which 
we can find out this?

Answer (score 1):

Just before dropping the temp table (or before closing the connection), select pg_stats into a table where you store all the information:

```
INSERT INTO history SELECT * FROM pg_stat_user_tables WHERE relname = 'temp_table';
```

Comment: @Frank Still to query `pg_stat_user_tables`, PostgreSQL statistics collector should be enabled. Any other way to find out without using statistics collector?